# \newif conditional causing problem in \typeout or \edef

Tags: conditionals, expansion

The following code produces result as expected, i.e.,

> False True

on the typeset document.

```
\documentclass{minimal}

\newif\iftest

\newcommand{\test}[2]{
\iftest
  #1
\else
  #2
\fi
}
\newcommand{\ex}{\test{True}{False}\testtrue\test{True}{False}}

\begin{document}
\ex
\end{document}
```

However, if I wrap `\ex` with `\typeout`, or try to `\edef\ex` instead of `\newcommand` I get:

```
! Incomplete \iffalse; all text was ignored after line...
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) You mean `\typeout` and not `\typeset`, right?

Comment: Please don't use the `minimal` class for [minimal working examples (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that). Despite the name it is not intended for that and can cause problems, because it does not define everything a real class does. Also a MWE should actually show what is *not* working, i.e. add the code which causes the trouble.

Comment: Martin: the above example uses nothing from a documentclass so minimal is a good choice here, or at least not a bad one ...

Comment: @Herbert: Yes, well `article` doesn't do any harm either. It is better to be consistent and because the OP is new here I mentioned it, so that he doesn't start any bad habits.

Comment: @Werner: yes, I meant `\typeout`. Will edit the question.

Comment: If you want to implement a "once only warning", put `\global\testtrue` *outside* the `\typeout`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The problem here is that `\testtrue` is not expandable and not protected and therefore fragile. It is defined as `\let\iftrue\iftrue`. In an expandable context like `\edef` or `\typeout` the `\let` assignment is ignored, and both if-switches are expanded. Because there is only one `\fi` (which is taken as part of `\iftrue`) the compiler complains about the missing `\fi`.

You can use `\test{<true>}{<false>}` in this context, but not `\testtrue` or `\testfalse`. So you would need to do the following:

```
\typeset{\test{True}{False}}
\testtrue
\typeset{\test{True}{False}}
```

---

I like to give you one more advice. I would define the `\test` macro as follows:

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\test}{%
  \iftest
    \expandafter\@firstoftwo
  \else
    \expandafter\@secondoftwo
  \fi
}
\makeatother
```

This way the if-statement is fully processed before one of the two arguments is processed. This avoid some issues with can arise when code is used inside and if-switch. For example defining a new if-switch with `\newif` *and* using it inside such an argument will break, if that argument is to be skipped.
The `\@firstoftwo` and `\@secondoftwo` macros simply take two arguments and expand to either the first or the second. The `\expandafter` expands (i.e. removes, in this case) the `\else` or `\fi` first. Also note the `%` after the `{` which is required to avoid a space being added there by the line break.

Comment: So I guess I've bumped in the moving argument problem. I've done some reading and as far as I understand, one can't simply jump out expansion, execute unexpandable token, and then continue expanding?

Comment: @JKS: No, you can't jump out.

Comment: So to make `\ex` work in `\typeout` (expanding context) I would have to use fully expandable macros, e.g. `\newcommand{\ex}{\testTrue\testFalse}` where `\newcommand{\testTrue}{True}` and `\newcommand{\testFalse}{False}`? There is no some complicated macro that could execute something in expansion only context?

Comment: @JKS: You need to do any non-expandable things, like assignments, outside the expanding macro. Not sure what you mean with expandsion-only context, but `\edef\foo{<content>}` expands it content fully. Non-expandable macros will stay the same.

Comment: I meant on total expansion, like in `\edef`, `\write`, `\typeout`, ...