# code fails to be wrapped with condition

Tags: tex-core, conditionals

In the following example, I want the content in `minipage` is highlighted by `\colorbox` if the condition is true. If the condition is false, the content in `minipage` typeset directly.

The typeset of true-branch however, is not highlighted. I think it is because of `\fi`.

Then,how to modify this code to make it work as expected?

Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\begin{document}

\ifnum 5>1 % or something like \ifx..., \if\empty..., and so on.
\colorbox{red} \fi
{\begin{minipage}{2in}The content maybe very large and complex, I don't want to duplicate it in both true-branch and false-branch\end{minipage}}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Similar: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/35810

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\myConditionTF[1]{%
  #1% or something like \ifx..., \if\empty..., and so on.
    \expandafter\@firstoftwo
  \else
    \expandafter\@secondoftwo
  \fi
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\myConditionTF{\ifnum 5>1\relax}
  {\colorbox{red}}
  {}
{\begin{minipage}{2in}The content maybe very large and complex, I don't want to duplicate it in both true-branch and false-branch\end{minipage}}
\qquad
\myConditionTF{\ifnum 5<1\relax}
  {\colorbox{red}}
  {}
{\begin{minipage}{2in}The content maybe very large and complex, I don't want to duplicate it in both true-branch and false-branch\end{minipage}}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Many thanks for this solution!! And why is `\enxpandafter` needed? Where or what is the details about `\@firstoftwo` and `@secondoftwo`?

Comment: @lyl To expand hence get rid of the `\else` and/or `\fi`. You can get more info about `\@firstoftwo` and `\secondoftwo` by searching for them on this site, the internet, or `texdoc macros2e`, and even by executing `latexdef -s \@firstoftwo` in terminal.

Comment: Also see [What do `\@firstoftwo` and `\@secondoftwo` do?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/21262/what-do-firstoftwo-and-secondoftwo-do)

Comment: The first test typesets the content with background color red as expected. When I remove `\relax` from its argument, the red color disappears. Since `#1` is wrapped by braces when calling this macro, why is `\relax` obligatory here?

Comment: @lyl Similar: [Use of \relax after \ifnum ... \fi construction](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/137207)